# How many :attr_accessor are too many for a class?

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

How many `:attr_accessor`s are too many for a `class`, or, what is the "right" number of such methods (if there is such a thing as a "right number")?

So, as a trivial example, take

```
class Example
  :attr_accessor :a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f, :g, :h, :i, :j, :k
  # instance methods here...
end
```

Obviously, sometimes a large number of such variables and the corresponding accessors are necessary (perhaps you'd see this in an `ActiveRecord::Model`); but I'm looking for a *decent heuristic* to use when determining whether to refactoring based on the raw number of instance variables within a class.

Answers highlighting and/or summarizing articles, presentation, books, etc. on this design issue are much appreciated.

Comment: so: why the downvote? I'm OK being down voted, but would appreciate a reason for doing so in the comments. Perhaps the question could be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object-oriented programming, if the methods that serve a class tend to be similar in many aspects, then the class is said to have high cohesion. In a highly cohesive system, code readability and reusability is increased, while complexity is kept manageable.

wiki here: [read me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)

and this book:
[Clean code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such thing as too many attribute accessors and there's no reason to refactor such code. If all those attributes are used and needed by that class than you can have as much as you need.

However, this might be a sign of breaking [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), so that's something to look out for.